# Stop HTML5 animation from outside the web browser

Tags: javascript, android, html, animation

I need to stop a HTML5 animation from outside the Web browser.

I have tablets that are showing HTML5 pages with animations.

So, I have a Web View (Basic4Android) in my Android Application that shows the HTML5 web pages.

When an event occurs on the App, I need to stop/pause/play/resume the HTML5 animation.

Is it possible? Is it possible to call javascript functions/events from the App?

Thanks!

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute javascript code which will stop animation on page. Please have a look at thread [Execute javascript from code](http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/forum/threads/execute-javascript-from-code.7020/)